# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'form': object is null or undefined: Validator.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery `validate.js` file for validations, if am including this file in my application it is throwing above titled error. Below is my code

**Javascript**

```
$().ready(function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function () {
            alert("submitted!");
        }
    });

    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 4,
                customvalidation: true,
                regex: "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
            },


            messages: {
                field: {
                    required: "Please enter name",
                    maxlength: "Maximum length allowed 4"
                },

            }


        }
    );

    $.validator.addMethod("customvalidation",

        function (value, element) {
            return /^[A-Za-z\d]+$/.test(value);
        },
        "Sorry, no special characters allowed");


    $.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
    }, "Only Characters from A-z");

});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
      <h1>Registration Form</h1>

    <div>
       <div id="tabs-1" style="width: 100%;">
       <table>

       <tr>
       <td align="right">
         <span style="color: Red">* </span>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Employee Name: " ></asp:Label>
           </td>
           <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="field" runat="server"  name="field"></asp:TextBox>

            </td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
       <td align="right">
           <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Validate" />

           </td>
           </tr>

       </table>
                       </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Note: Also there is one observation that when I when I accessed the js and css files from the website url then it is working fine. I guess some files may be missing. Please assist here.

Comment: If it works when you include the files from elsewhere, and you already know files are missing, just fix it.  Not understanding what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have some serious syntax errors in your code...

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 4,
            customvalidation: true,
            regex: "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
        },
        messages: { // <- this does not go inside of "rules" option
            field: {
                required: "Please enter name",
                maxlength: "Maximum length allowed 4"
            },  // <- extra comma
        }
    }
);  // <- missing closing brace "}"
```

1)  You incorrectly have `messages` *inside* `rules` as a sibling of `field`.  `messages` is a sibling of `rules`.

2)  You are missing a closing brace at the end.  Should be `});` instead of `);`.

3)  You have a trailing comma within `messages`.  Although sloppy, this will only be an issue in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Fixed code:

```
$("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,
            maxlength: 4,
            customvalidation: true,
            regex: "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        field: {
            required: "Please enter name",
            maxlength: "Maximum length allowed 4"
        }
    }
});
```

**Side-note:**

As per [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), this is "not recommended"...

```
$().ready(function () {
```

It should really be changed to `$(document).ready(function () {` or `$(function () {`